# not showing top border on mui accordion when its expanded

Tags: css, material-ui, border, accordion

When I expand the accordion, its top border disappears. However, the border is visible when the accordion is collapsed.
I have tried adding a top border, but it makes the border bolder when the accordion is not expanded. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.